# How to partition table rows get the min and max for each process

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Can someone please let me know how to get the output from first table. please note that I am not allowed to use loops. I tried with window functions and no luck yet.

```
CUSTOMER_NUMBER ORDER_NO PROCESS
100             1001        1
100             1002        1
100             1003        2
100             1004        2
100             1005        2
100             1006        3
100             1007        3
100             1008        3
101             1009        1
101             1010        1
101             1011        2
101             1012        2
101             1013        2

CUSTOMER_NUMBER MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE, PROCESS
100             1001        1002            1
100             1003        1005            2
100             1006        1008            3
101             1009        1010            1
101             1011        1013            2
```

Comment: Can someone please let me know how to get the output from first table. please note that I am not allowed to use loops.  I tried with window functions and no luck yet.

Comment: can you have repeating process for a customer_number? also tag the database being used.

Comment: There is no repeating for process per customer. this is for Redshift

Comment: you can just use `group by customer_number,process` and get the min,max

Comment: sorry about misleading info. there is no process column.  I added that to make it clear. but forgot to remove it

Comment: what's the logic then? edit the question and add all the required info in there.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
select
  min(ORDER_NO) as MIN_VALUE,
  max(ORDER_NO) as MAX_VALUE,
  PROCESS
from yourTable
group by PROCESS
```

Answer (score 0):

if you would like to get the results by window functions you could use max() over() and min() over() window functions:

```
 SELECT
  customer_number,
  order_no,
  min(order_no)
  OVER (
    PARTITION BY customer_number, process ) AS min_value,
  max(order_no)
  OVER (
    PARTITION BY customer_number, process ) AS max_value,
  process
FROM table_1
```

This will yield the original table with additional 2 columns (min_value, max_value).